# Mobile toggle efffect

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am working on a big commerce cms, and I was wondering is it possible to have mobile like toggle effect on all screen resolution except desktop, Thankyou in advance

```html
 <div id="top-nav">
            <div class="CategoryList" id="TopCategoryList">
                <div class="SideCategoryListClassic">
                    <nav>
                    <ul class="category-list" style="padding-top: 3px;">
                        <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-tire-warmers">MOTO-D Tire Warmers</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/pro-series-motorcycle-stands">MOTO-D Stands</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/cnc-motorcycle-parts">Bonamici Rearsets</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-gps-lap-timer">MOTO-D "Next" GPS Lap Timer</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-undersuits-and-baselayers">MOTO-D Undersuit</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/spark-italy-exhaust-technologies">Spark Italy Exhausts</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/performance-riding-motorcycle-accessories">Accessories</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: What is a _mobile like toggle effect_?

Comment: it means toggle, on small screen for mobile menu,sorry for my bad english

Comment: np for the english, but are you talking about [off-canvas menus](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_off-canvas.asp)? In that case you'd have to create both menus and hide one with media queries. If you mean something like what @Rajan Benipuri posted, you can make the menu always visible and hide the toggle for some screen sizes. Basically [media-queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) are what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using simple jQuery

[check the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/demaxglobal/9g7552Lb/)

```
 <div id="toggle-nav">
  Toggle
 </div>
<div id="top-nav">
        <div class="CategoryList" id="TopCategoryList">
            <div class="SideCategoryListClassic">
                <nav>
                <ul class="category-list" style="padding-top: 3px;">
                    <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-tire-warmers">MOTO-D Tire Warmers</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/pro-series-motorcycle-stands">MOTO-D Stands</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/cnc-motorcycle-parts">Bonamici Rearsets</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-gps-lap-timer">MOTO-D "Next" GPS Lap Timer</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-undersuits-and-baselayers">MOTO-D Undersuit</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/spark-italy-exhaust-technologies">Spark Italy Exhausts</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/performance-riding-motorcycle-accessories">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>

 <script>
   $('#toggle-nav').click(function(){
   $('#top-nav').toggle();
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: How can i achieve this with media querry?

Comment: Please explain your question a bit

Comment: I am trying to achieve mobile toggle on all screen resolution,I know there is a toggle in menu for mobile,but i also want that for desktop also

Comment: This code will toggle the menu in all screen resolution. There is nothing like you can toggle it in mobile only.

Answer (score 0):

On of the variant - using slideToggle

```
$('#toggle-nav').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#top-nav').slideToggle();
 });
```